# Host the wp-admin on another domain?

Tags: redirect, subdomains

Currenly I have a client that has a WordPress running on, let's say, `www.example.com`.

I'm working on a new version using another technology/language that will be hosted on another server.. But the administration (WP) and the database will stay on old server.

So basically I will need to point the `www.example.com` to the new host (no problem here) and create a subdomain like `admin.example.com` that will point to the old server with the WP installation.

I'm afraid that this will make a mess on the database while storing `options` and `guids` for posts and attachments URLs... They will be stored as `admin.example.com` and not `www.example.com`, am I right?

How to make the wp-admin run on `admin.example.com` and store URLs on the database as `www.example.com`? This would work for the preview links too?

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps this thread can be useful: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/login-subdomain?

Comment: @KristerAndersson the problem wasn't solved on the topic, and the links are 404 :(

Comment: As this sounds interesting I did some searching and realized that this is pretty hard to achieve. Unfortunately I don't have the time to try it out myself. Anyway, it seems like [someone got at least something similar working](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-admin-be-moved-to-a-non-public-server-must-dns-name-of-admin-match-blog#post-5324968).

Comment: @thiago Belem, would you please let me know how you have resolved it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easy solution would be adding this line to your `wp-config.php` of your admin server code.

> define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

Then you can access it without modifying the database option.

Comment: Works great! Wordpress.org states that this is a little bit insecure, but the only way to access my admin portal is from a VPN, and the original domain has the "/wp-admin/" path blocked; so, this is great for this use case! :)

Answer (score 2):

What I would do (I was actually doing that many times) is:

- Change the domain name for the existing WP installation using, for example, [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). Then, everything on your old site will get the "admin.example" links.
- Change the URLs back when retrieve DB records to use on the new site. When I was doing that, I never accessed the "admin" DB directly. Instead, I had a script that was taking only the tables and records I needed and copied from "admin" to "www" servers.

Comment: This would be my last resource... Because this would break, for example, preview links inside the admin

Comment: @TiuTalk No, everything in WordPress will work. The preview links will have the "admin" URLs, and will work. But, on the "www" site, you will replace the "admin" part with "www".

Comment: Thats the point, I can't use preview links with "admin." because they would only work on the "www."

Comment: You could use `preview_post_link` filter to adjust the URLs.

Comment: @TiuTalk You will have two parts of your application:

A) the admin part, WP-based, will have the admin.example.com URL, and all links in it, including preview links will have the admin.example.com URLs.

B) The production part, with the www.example.com URL, not WP-based, but your "other technology" will have all URLs starting with "www" instead of "admin" because when you transfer DB from "admin" to "production", you will replace "admin" with "www".

Why won't this work?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this with pure Apache server configuration, no need to customize WordPress settings...

https://tec.libertar.se/how-to-host-wordpress-admin-on-a-seperate-domain-and-subfolder/